# Apache Poi - how do I read the xlsx and write on the row that contains no information?

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to make an application that can read a .xlsx file and write on the row that does not contain any information. I have tried using something like:

```
 FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);

        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row1;
        Cell cell1;
        Cell cell2;
        int incrementator=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int t = 0; t < 18; t++) {

                cell1=sheet.getRow(i).getCell(t);

                if(cell1==null){

                   cell2 = sheet.createRow(incrementator).createCell(0);
                   cell2.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                   cell2.setCellValue("Something");
                   System.out.println("Succes");
                }else{

                   incrementator++;
                   System.out.println("Incrementing"+incrementator);
                }
```

I know it's bad, but maybe it can help you understand what i'm trying to do.
Any help would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: `sheet.getRow(i)` doesn't necessarily return a row, it can also return `null`, so you must check the result. If it is null, you must create the row first.

Comment: Why arent you using CellIterator and RowIterator? See - http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);

Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

    if(sheet.getRow(i).getPhysicalNumberOfCells() == 0){
        //row is 'empty' : do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to find getNumberOfRows() , is it getPhysicalNumberOfRows() or getRowNum()?

Answer (score 0):

[Sheet.getRow(int)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow%28int%29) can return null, if the row hasn't been used or styled. In such a case, you need to create the row before you can use it. So, your code would want to be something like:

```
Worbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("workbook.xlsx"));
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Row row1 = sheet.getRow(0);
if (row1 == null) {
   // First row hasn't been touched, so create it
   row1 = sheet.createRow(1);
}

Cell cell1;
Cell cell2;
// etc
```

Also, [if you have a file, use the file, don't use an inputstream](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)!